# Inserting schema Programmatically

Tags: java, database, postgresql, schema

We have an enterprise application based on spring-java that offers each user(one corporation) its own database.So when a new user (corp.) registers to us they give us location of their database (a postgreSQL) and We need to make their blank database filled with our schema and our data.

My ques:

I need to automate the  process of inserting a **schema** in database programatically.

How I think I should do it:
 I will create some procedure that will execute commands related to inserting schema into a provided database but I am not sure this is a plausible way.

Are such kind of process we can perform with APIs of database connectors? I'm afraid not.

Please people share your thoughts, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at flyaway and liquibase

- http://flywaydb.org/
- http://www.liquibase.org/

Both of these tools support creating a schema from scratch (run all scripts) or running a subset of scripts on an existing database to move from version A to version B.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest, but is it possible to do it the way i mentioned?

Comment: Neither of these tools use a stored procedure. Instead, SQL (or even XML) files are executed against a database. The great thing that you get from this is versioning. And, you can check your scripts into source control (git / subversion)

Answer (score 2):

I think doing it the way you describe is horrible, and you should use existing tools like those Lance mentioned that already do that job, and do it fairly well.

If you insist on doing it in your program, you can run DDL statements directly through PgJDBC or whatever.

If you insist on also wrapping it in stored procedures (why?!?), you can generate DDL as strings and run DDL with the PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_table() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE test (x integer);';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(I'm assuming you don't want to just write the DDL and shove it in a procedure as ordinary statements, because that would be even weirder when you could just use an SQL script).